# Dependabot cannot create a pull request as one or more other dependencies require a version that is incompatible with this update

Tags: github

In one of my repositories today, I got this security notification:

```
The kramdown gem before 2.3.0 for Ruby processes the template option inside Kramdown documents by default, which allows unintended read access (such as template="/etc/passwd") or unintended embedded Ruby code execution (such as a string that begins with template=" string://<%= `).

 NOTE: kramdown is used in Jekyll, GitLab Pages, GitHub Pages, and Thredded Forum.
```

I tried creating a dependabot security update but it couldn't update to the required version.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem in a few repositories this week. They were all using GitHub pages to generate static sites, so the JSON vulnerability was probably irrelevant. However, it's easier if you can just upgrade away from the vulnerable version of kramdown.

The problem with my repositories was that they were using versions of the [`github-pages` gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/github-pages/versions/207) older than 207. Those required vulnerable versions of kramdown, so Dependabot wouldn't touch it. I'm not sure why Dependabot couldn't update `github-pages`.

To solve it, I used the [`bundle update --all` command](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-update.1.html). `bundle update github-pages` also works, although in my project it had the same result. It installed a bunch of updates, and recorded them in the `Gemfile.lock` file. When I committed that change, the security notification on GitHub went away.

Comment: The problem is back with `kramdown 2.3.0`, see https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-52p9-v744-mwjj . Atm, `bundle update` does not solve the problem since the latest `github-pages` does not allow `kramdown 2.3.1`.  But it seems like a fix is on the way: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/767

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it by modifying the **Gemfile.lock** file, it is located in the root directory of the repository.

> **CTRL + F**  kramdown

Appears in three places in the file

```
Gemfile.lock 
line 70  kramdown (= 1.17.0) update to 2.3.0
line 105 kramdown (~> 1.14)  update to 2.3.0
line 170 kramdown (1.17.0)   update to 2.3.0
```

Create a new branch to modify, commit, and submit the changes.
Open Pull Request, merge and confirm merge.

Then tell me how it went.
Regards

Comment: I guess you meant for line 203, not line 170 here.

Comment: Hm, with this I get "kramdown has no parser to handle the specified input format: GFM" … seems that the `kramdown-parser-gfm` Gem has to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Clone that repo locally. Run `npm update`. It will automatically update all your packages. No need to rely on dependabot. To verify the update run `npm outdated`.

To upgrade yarn.lock dependencies, run `yarn upgrade --latest`.